# GridView changes tiles when scrolled

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to create a View like here in Fever app.

[image]

So basically, when clicking on a tile it changes its background, clicking again restores the image. I do it in a GridView, all the system works etc, however, when I scroll down the View and then up again, the layout redisplays the tiles as not selected (with an image, even though I have clicked on them before). Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Kind regards,

Grzegorz

As asked here is my adapter Code:

```
public class IssueTileAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> issues;

    public IssueTileAdapter(Context context, List<String> issuesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.issues = issuesList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return issues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return issues.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View root = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.issue_tile, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();

        ImageView tvIssueImage = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.iv_issue_image);
        TextView tvIssueTitle = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tv_issue_title);

        tvIssueImage.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(issues.get(position).replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase(), "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
        tvIssueTitle.setText(issues.get(position));

        return root;
    }

    public static int getDrawable(Context context, String name)
    {
        Assert.assertNotNull(context);
        Assert.assertNotNull(name);

        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

And here is the onClickMethod.

```
IssueTileAdapter adapter = new IssueTileAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), issueList);
        issuesGrid.setAdapter(adapter);

        issuesGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                issueName=issueList.get(position);
                Log.d("NAME CLICKED",issueList.get(position));
                if(!issues.contains(issueName)) {
                    issues.add(issueName);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.shadow_cast).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.iv_issue_image).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    deleteIssue(issueName);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.shadow_cast).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.iv_issue_image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you saving any state which item you have clicked?

Comment: I add it to the list the user will have of the things selected, but otherwise now. Should I do onSavedInstance or something?

Comment: Post your adapter code for generating each item

Answer (score 0):

Pass `issues` to `IssueTileAdapter` and use the this code inside `getView` method

```
            issueName=issueList.get(position);
            if(!issues.contains(issueName)) {

                view.findViewById(R.id.shadow_cast).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                view.findViewById(R.id.iv_issue_image).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{

                view.findViewById(R.id.shadow_cast).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.findViewById(R.id.iv_issue_image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

In `getView` you are initializing  always same way. You have to checked if it was clicked previously . If clicked set up with your clicked requirements and not setup with your different requirements.